# Microsoft error while synchronizing call from IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, synchronization, visual-studio-debugging, microsoft-sync-framework

I get the below error

> `***`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {046C184F-2188-4C99-A95A-9C0DCDC19050} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`***`

while using the Microsoft Sync Services on execute of the below statement .

I get the error only when I run from the IIS that is http;//localhost/S71/default.aspx etc. But if I run by pressing F5 from my visual studio it works fine .

All other code like the "Provisioning process" everything works just fine only while I run from the IIS only and on the .Synchronize() method I get the error.

```
// Execute the synchronization process
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which Sync Fx did you install? x86 or x64? if it is x86, check that your app pool is configured for 32-bit apps as well by setting the "Enable 32-bit applications"